# List not recognized using ManyToOne relationship with SQLiteNetExtensions

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I get the following exception from CreateTable:

"Don't know about System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SurgeArrestor.SAAnswer]"

This is a Xamarin Forms app with the following packages:
[Package list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptB23.png)

Here is my code:

```
// SAForm.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SurgeArrestor
{
    public class SAForm
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public long SAFormID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_formID")]
        public long FormID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_formDate")]
        public string FormDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_formNotes")]
        public string FormNotes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_formAnswers")]
        [OneToMany(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
        public List<SAAnswer> FormAnswers { get; set; }
    }
}

// SAAnswer.cs
using System;
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions.Attributes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SurgeArrestor
{
    [Table("SAAnswer")]
    public class SAAnswer
    {
        public SAAnswer() { }

        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public long SAAnswerID { get; set; } 

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_formAnswerID")]
        public long FormAnswerID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_formID")]
        public long FormID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_questionID")]
        public long QuestionID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_answer")]
        public Boolean Answer { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof(SAForm))]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public long SAFormID { get; set; }

    }
}


// SAFormTable.cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SQLite;
using SQLiteNetExtensions;

namespace SurgeArrestor
{
    public class SAFormTable : SQLiteConnection
    {
        static object locker = new object();

        public SAFormTable(string dbPath) : base(dbPath)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                CreateTable<SAForm>();  // throws exception
            }
        }
     // MORE CODE
}
```

This is my first Xamarin.Forms app. I have worked with a Xamarin app using the MVVMCross.Community.Plugin.Sqlite / SQLiteNetExtensions-MvvmCross packages and used that to model these classes.

Have I missed something in the translation? As far as I can tell the net extensions package provides support of the same ManyToOne implementation.

Searching in stack overflow and google did not provide any specific results and the examples I found all seem to follow what I have here.

Thanks for any insight / suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One-to-Many collections are just that - **collections**. `List` is a special type of collection that supports ordering and indexing - something that is not inherently supported in SQL databases.

Try changing your property from

```
List<SAAnswer> FormAnswers { get; set; }
```

to

```
ICollection<SAAnswer> FormAnswers { get; set; }
```